# how to redirect to next page with radio button without submit button?

Tags: javascript, php

## this code is providing the submit button

### the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_action(form) {
    form.action = document.querySelector('input[name = "x"]:checked').value;;
}
```

### html form

```
<form name = "quoted" method="get" onsubmit="get_action(this);">
 <input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" required="required" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">     <br>
 <textarea class = "actual_quote" name = "actual_quote" required="required" placeholder = "Write the question here!"></textarea><br><br><br>
 <div class = "checkboxes" required="required">
     <h3 style = "margin-top:-20px;">Please select one catagory that the quote falls into.</h3>
     <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupid.php" id = "x" checked="checked" />    <span>stupid</span></label><br>
     <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupider.php" id = "x" /> <span>stupider</span>    </label><br>
     <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupidest.php" id = "x"/>    <span>stupidest</span></label>
 </div>
 <input id = "submit1" type="submit"><br>
```

Comment: I want when i click the radio  it will redirect to the next page and above is having the submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. dont mix your code-style between `class=""` and `class = ""`
2. div cant have a required
3. id must be unique
4. use jQuery for it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
// debug output
    console.log('Document ready');
    $('#submit1').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 var redirect = $('input[name=x]:checked', '#quoted').val();
 alert (redirect);
 location.href = redirect;
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <form id="quoted">
  <input id="poster" type="text" name="poster" required="required" placeholder="Credited Individual."><br>
  <textarea class="actual_quote" name="actual_quote" required="required" placeholder="Write the question here!"></textarea><br><br><br>
  <div class = "checkboxes" required="required">
   <h3 style = "margin-top:-20px;">Please select one catagory that the quote falls into.</h3>
   <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupid.php" checked="checked" />    <span>stupid</span></label><br>
   <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupider.php"/> <span>stupider</span>    </label><br>
   <label for="x"><input type="radio" name="x" value="stupidest.php"/>    <span>stupidest</span></label>
  </div>
  <input id="submit1" type="button"><br>
 </form>
  </body>
```